# Regarding Azure API Connection through JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

That Might be a trivial question for many, but I am pretty new to azure environment and I am looking forward to access data underlying azure subscriptions and resource groups, so regarding that I Know I have to hit the REST endpoints in order to obtain result, but before that, in order to connect what is the API that I should look into, if any help could be provided in order to start writing code to obtain data from underlying Subscriptions. So can anyone help with the API I should look into, and how to start with them.
Also if there are resources where I can look into in order to obtain a start working with Azure API, that would also be really helpful 
That will  be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you can use Azure SDK for Java to check whether meet your requirement.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java. Also, you can see this document about azure for java development(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/ ).

Because the SDK encapsulates lots of REST endpoints and you can use it easily. 
Meanwhile, could you please describe the more details about your requirement about access what's data?

Comment: Thanks Will, that was really helpful, I am trying to get Virtual Machine compute name, which can be accessed by Virtual Machine Interface of com.microsoft.azure.management.compute package, but I am not able to access this particular interface,
Link to the interface and its methods 
https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/VirtualMachine.html